# Remove editing time in MUI MobileTimePicker

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How do I remove the keyboard input in the mobile time (and I suppose the same solution would be used for the date picker as well) picker.

More specifically, how can I remove this icon?

[image]

I know on desktop keyboard input can be disabled by modifying the onKeyDown event like so:

```
onKeyDown={(e) => e.preventDefault()}
```

But this doesn't take effect in the mobile view. In any case, that wouldn't be an elegant solution, because I don't want the user to be able to enter into the view with the text edit (below) at all.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just used styling to remove the icons. This styling applies to both the mobile time picker and the mobile date picker.

```
.MuiTimePickerToolbar-root > .MuiGrid-root > .MuiButtonBase-root, 
.MuiPickersToolbar-root > .MuiGrid-root > .MuiButtonBase-root {
  display: none;
}
```